# Getting JQuery load() in a variable for validation instead of displaying it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Here what i m using**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $("#box").load("read.txt"); // i want read.txt content in variable
  });
});
```

this code is working fine but i want the content in variable.

Comment: where will the variable be driven from? do you have supporting HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use this

```
function validate(content) {
    alert(content); // check your content here
}
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    //$("#box").load("read.txt"); // skip this line
    $.get('read.txt',validate); // new line
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `$.load` method loads a url, and outputs it's contents into a jQuery DOM element.
It is a shorthand for the `$.ajax` method, but preconfigured to write the result into an element.

You can use the original `$.ajax` method or one of it's other shorthands to better suit your needs.

[jQuery Ajax Shorthand methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/)

[jQuery Ajax Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Indeed an easy solution to this would look like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function(){
    $.get("read.txt",function(data){
      console.log(data); // data contains the contents of read.txt in string format
    });
  });
});
```